# CheckCaseOnly doesn't work, while CheckSpelling does

Tags: apache2, ubuntu

I'm trying to globally set `CheckCaseOnly on` to make my webservers folders case insensitive. It doesn't work though?

I don't need it to correct spelling - thus I'm not using `CheckSpelling`.

Apache2.4 on Ubuntu.
mod_speling is enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the [mod_speling documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html).  The CheckCaseOnly directive does not enable the module on its own.  You would need to *both* turn on mod_speling and also put in the check case only directive:

```
CheckSpelling on
CheckCaseOnly on
```

When it is configured like this, mod_speling doesn't correct any spelling, it only corrects the case.  This is a very awkward set of configuration directives.  You might expect that this would check spelling as well, but it doesn't.

If you leave out the `CheckSpelling on`, the module isn't enabled and it can't correct spelling or case.  If you leave out the `CheckCaseOnly on`, it corrects both spelling and case.  It is only with both directives on that it doesn't check spelling but does correct for case.